# Translation of "Have you been to any of them?"

Tags: traduction

"There are many good French restaurants in New York. Have you been to any of them?"

> Il y a beaucoup de bons restaurants français à New York. Avez-vous mangé à ____ ?

What should be the translation for "any of them"? Is it *quelques-uns d'entre eux*, *quelques-uns parmi eux*, or what?

Also, I'm not sure if "have you been" can be translated directly with *Avez-vous été*, or should we rather use the verb *mangé* or *visité*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using "essayer" for "try" or "Êtes-vous allé".
As for "any of them", you might wanna try "à quelques-uns" or "à l'un d'entre eux"

Comment: If we just use *à quelques-uns*, do we need to insert *en* (since it's *à quelques-uns des restaurants*)?

Comment: @user11550 It's best to say "d'entre eux" since repeating restaurant 2 times would be repetitive and look bad. "à quelques-uns d'entre eux". As for inserting "en" I'm not sure I understand your question. Just saying "Il y a beaucoup de bons restaurants français à New York. êtes-vous allé à quelques-uns" would be acceptable too.

Comment: For *en*, I mean it is often inserted in sentences like "Il y **en** a beaucoup". So I was wondering whether we should say "Vous **en** êtes à quelques-uns?".

Comment: @user11550 No, in this case it would make no sense.

Comment: On ne peut pas aller "à" un restaurant. On va "dans" un restaurant. On ne peut pas non plus dire "à quelques uns" (sans tiret), ou alors il faut reformuler et dire à la place: En avez-vous visité quelques uns?

Comment: Je suis de l'avis de PERCE-NEIGE, utiliser "quelques-uns" pour compléter "Avez-vous mangé à" fait mal aux oreilles, la phrase doit être reformulée. Néanmoins les suggestions "à l'un d'entre eux" et celles portant sur les verbes sont pertinentes. Ce sur quoi je ne suis pas d'accord avec PERCE-NEIGE est que, certes on ne dit jamais "à un restaurant", mais "à l'un d'entre eux" est tout à fait correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would say :

> Il y a beaucoup de bons restaurants français à New York. Avez-vous été à l'un d'entre eux ?

Comment: Dans l'un d'entre eux. On ne peut pas utiliser "à" ici, car on ne va pas "à" un restaurant, mais "dans". "Avoir été" est d'un registre très familier.

Answer (score 0):

> Il y a beaucoup de bons restaurants français à New York. Avez-vous
>   mangé à ____ ?

Les réponses données ne sont pas justes, car on ne peut absolument jamais dire "à" un restaurant. On doit dire "au restaurant" ou "dans un restaurant".

- Vous êtes vous rendu dans l'un d'entre eux?
- Avez-vous déjà mangé dans l'un d'entre eux?
- Etes-vous déjà allé dîner dans l'un d'entre eux?

Les possibilités sont infinies pratiquement.

"In any of them, se traduit par: *dans l'un d'entre eux*, ou *dans l'un d'eux*, mais ici, la première forme semble plus indiquée.

Les seules fois où on peut dire: Avez-vous déjà mangé à/au....
C'est quand on donne le nom d'un restaurant.

Ex:

- J'ai pris un café au *café de Flore*.
- *J'ai pris un dessert à La Tour d'Argent*.

Mais:

- J'ai mangé ***dans un restaurant*** qui s'appelle La Tour d'Argent.
- Je vais souvent ***au restaurant***.
- J'aime bien traîner ***dans les restaurants***.
- Je me suis perdu ***dans le restaurant***.